# How i can load image from WEB-INF dir [Openshift:Vaadin]

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, vaadin, openshift

i have some problems with loading image file in openshift based application.
I load image with this code:

```
private Image rankImage = new Image();
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(VaadinService
                .getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + String.format("/WEB-INF/images/level%d.png", user.getRank().getLevel())));
rankImage.setSource(resource);
```

And it's work on my local server. In browser this image like as:

```
src="http://localhost:8080/ROOT/APP/connector/1/47/source/level1.png"
```

But, in the openshif app it's didn't work, and look like:

```
src="http://<my-app-name>/APP/connector/0/17/source/level1.png"
```

Images stored in /WEB-INF/images/image-name.png
How i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was fix this problem. Solution is:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="...">
...
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <!-- ADD THIS -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
  </build>
</project>
```

**java.class**

```
private Image rankImage = new Image();
rankImage.setSource(new ClassResource(String.format("/images/level%d.png", 1)));
```

Images stored in:

```
WEB-INF
|_images
  |_level1.png
  |_level2.png
  |_level3.png
```